# C# SendMessage отправку двух языков

Tags: c#

Нужно чтобы программа брала из textbox текст и отправляла, по нажатию кнопки, в то место, где грубо говоря ее вставят, будь то строчка в браузере или ещё что. Но проблема в том, что SendKeys.Send отправляет только на одном языке, если у меня будет включена русская раскладка и я захочу отправить "test тест" отправится "еуст тест". Решение в гугле найти не могу. Пробывал через буфер обмена Clipboard.SetText(), он тоже не особо дружит с русским, через раз работает

Пробывал

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(
    text[i].Text, 
    false,      
    5,          
    200);
```

P.S SendKeys работает только на той раскладке, на которой была введена последняя буква

Comment: Если вы используете буфер обмета, то зачем вам вообще `SendKeys` ?

Comment: Буфер обмена использовал в качестве альтернативного варианта, он работает не правильно, с русским языком вообще не срабатывает.